# Wine glitch or Lubuntu 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, wine, lubuntu

Ok, i've been using wine to try to run windows programs (duh) well i was recently trying to run Everquest. which winehq gave a gold. It runs just fine for what i would expect for my system. but heres the rub. after playing for maybe 5-15 minutes it freezes i ctl+alt+delete and it says that eq.exe is using over 16,000,000 TB of memory... what i need to know is, is this a glitch with wine or lubuntu? also, help sorting out this mess would be appreciated. Here is a pic of my task manager before i kill the process.

[image: My Task Manager During lock up!]

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you have the stable version of Wine (which at the date of the response is Wine 1.4.1), in the Wine AppDB says this (http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=2939):

> Needs the full winetricks directx9 package, after that installation
>   and run went flawlessly.
>
> If armor or characters are missing/invisible this can be resolved by
>   setting the option VertexShaders in eqclient.ini from TRUE to FALSE.

If this doesn't fix your problem (because you have it applied yet), maybe deleting the `~/.wine` folder and generating it again will fix it (and also reinstalling the program because deleting the folder will delete all the programs and configurations of Wine) or trying other version of the graphic card drivers or Wine version.

Comment: yeah i checked winehd in order to get it to work at all. everything displays correctly its the fact that its freezing up and displaying almost 17million TB of memory used. currently using 1.4.1